# Postgresql : How to perform similar functionality as exchange partition like we have in Oracle?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, database-partitioning

New in postgresql ...

Is it possible to implement the same functionality of exchange as we have in oracle.

As per the requirement,

I want to insert the records in Table S which have many partition(LIST)
in non working hours I executed the job which moves the records from TABLE S -> TABLE P via TABLE E. we have this functionality in oracle.

in postgresql we have the functionality of attach and detach partition.

but not sure how to perform the above steps to move paritition in postgresql, as we cannot have same partition name in TABLE S and TABLE P.

Comment: Detach from `S`, then attach to `P`?

Comment: but not possible to have the same name of partitions in both the tables

Comment: we have partition by list, say as profession is the column name on which i set the partition. so we have the partition table as 'profession' in P. then I cannot have the same partition in S.

Comment: You can put them into different schemas.

Comment: and then next time time, i have to create partition for S table again before inserting the data ?

Comment: What does `via TABLE E` mean? So I guess in Oracle, you use exchange partition to ingest TABLE E (which is nonpartitioned table), and then again exchange partition to insert into TABLE P, like `ALTER TABLE P EXCHANGE PARTITION non_working_hours WITH TABLE E;`? If so, in postgres, you can detach `S` into `E`, rename `E` and attach to `P`

Comment: Please post the exact Oracle statements that you want to have in PostgreSQL. *exchange partition* in Oracle swaps data between one *non partitioned* table and one *partition* of a *partitioned table*. So there are no three objects as in your description...